# Training and prediction via Tensorflow

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning

I have just started coding with TensorFlow and I have classified Images.
Is there any possibility of making a prediction based on testing data?
How can I predict missing value based on the model?

Comment: what do you mean "predict missing value based on the model"?

Comment: when I use Matlab I give it testing Images as well as training Images. and after training, I use those images to test program accuracy.Those testing images are apart from training one. (2 separate folders) I wanted to know whether we have this kind of programming on TensorFlow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Question

*Does Tensorflow have the capability to read training data and test data from two separate files?*

## Answer

Yes!  Here is an [example of processing Iris data](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/tflearn), an intro machine learning data set for Tensorflow.

If you look at the code you will see the following lines

```
IRIS_TRAINING = "iris_training.csv"
IRIS_TEST = "iris_test.csv"
```

The data is clearly separated into training and test files.  You don't have to separate your data into different files in Tensorflow, but it certainly supports it and this tutorial link shows how to do it.

Comment: Thanks,  @wontonimo for sharing this page.It sounds great. Is there any other video-based tutorial like this page??

Comment: no thanks, just upvote.  This dude (although kinda crazy) makes learning Tensorflow fun https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0xVqLJe9_CY

Comment: with this tutorial could I predict my Images? I want to classify and detect Alfalfa from another plant.in order to do this should I give it Sepal Width, ..... or images?How can I train it for my images?https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/tflearn

Comment: yes, Tensorflow works with images.  There is a tutorial for that also : https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/mnist/beginners

Comment: If you are looking for something really really basic to get you over how-to-do-really-basic-things try this tutorial I wrote https://github.com/panchishin/learn-to-tensorflow